# Однопиксельные сдвиги блоков при зуме

Tags: css

Периодически при зуме разных сайтов встречаются однопиксельные сдвиги блоков разных (в результате чего может поехать вёрстка, что не есть приятно)
Из-за чего такие сдвиги происходят и как с ними бороться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разве что зум делать кратным единице (2.0, 3.0)... Сдвиг на пиксель происходит потому, что при зуме браузер умножает все габариты элементов на множитель увеличения (зум), после чего округляет (иногда - в большую сторону, иногда - в меньшую)

Comment: пичаль. а со стороны разработчика с этим что делать?) если жалуются.